# IIS no contesta responde al nombre de dominio del binding

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

Durante la semana pasada instalé las actualizaciones de windows y el servidor web dejó de funcionar.

Antes cuando accedía a midominio.com, contestaba la web, sin embargo, ahora me sale un error diciendo connection refused (google chrome). Si quito los bindigs y lo pongo por ip si funciona bien, pero cuando el binding para que solo conteste a peticiones de midominio.com me sale el error de connection refused.